# create struct containing fields of another struct

Tags: go, struct

How can I make a struct with fields of another struct

```
struct box {
    x int
    y int
}

struct textbox {
    BOXVALUES
    text string
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  The mcve should be compilable without errors, if your question is not about the occurring error. Use comments to insert your pseudo code, e.g. `/* BOXVALUES */`. Also show code to illustrate how you would like to use the resulting struct. I.e. write some compilable code which accesses the member "string" inside a variable of type textbox. Accompanied by another pseudocode in comment to show your idea of how to access the member "x" inside the variable.

Comment: What keeps you from declaring a member of type box inside the struct textbox and access it as `MyTextboxVariable.BoxMember.x` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have least 2 way:

case 1: called Embed

```
struct textbox {
    box
    text string
}
```

case 2: include child struct

```
struct textbox {
    boxValue box
    text string
}
```

But I  think you should learn basic lesson. This is a basic concept.

Answer (score 5):

Go doesn't have the concept of inheritance like say Java, where you can say that textbox is a child of box and thus inherits its fields.

So you can do this:

```
type box struct {
  x int
  y int
}

type textbox struct {
  box
  text string
}
```

By specifying type `box` without a struct field name you copy the fields defined in the `box` struct *int* `textbox`. However during construction you still have to explicitly initialise `box` fields as:

```
t := textbox {
  box: box{
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
  },
  text: "aoeu",
}
```

However you no longer need to reference `box` within `textbox` for access, for example:

```
println(t.x)
```

Go is a little weird in that regards, as `struct` isnt an object so `textbox` doesnt actually inherit from `box`, but rather have it copied into it whith some syntactical sugar for access.

Answer (score -2):

Not familiar with GO...but given the syntax it looks like you want

```
struct textbox
{
    BOXVALUES box
    text string
}
```

According to the syntax you gave which is all have to go on at the moment the struct should consist of a

```
fieldname DataType
```

In your example for the Textbox you are missing the DataType...like int, string, float, etc.  Your box struct is basically a new DataType so you can use it in place of where you would a DataType.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate in terms of go syntax on two counts - { on its own line is not valid syntax like in C, and the lone identifier `BOXVALUES` inside of a struct can refer to a struct or interface type, in which case the field name is the same as the type name (though these are called anonymous fields)